# Changing browser URL

Tags: php, html, url

I was wondering if they is a way to change the url so it doesn't show the product `id` at the end. Because this way someone can change the pid and it might direct them to a different page if that pid is in the database.

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($apages) ?>item.php?pid=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>">View</a>
```

`http://WWW.testexample.x10.mx/item/item.php?pid=2`

Comment: friendly / pretty URL's is what I think you are referring to, and what many CMS and ecom platforms provide.  Are you building this link and product page from scratch? or are you working in a open source platform like oscommerce or oscmax or even cms made simple?

Comment: Regarding your problem you should think about access rights for specific pages if you don't want users to get there. Tell us why you exactly want to cover the id.

Comment: Obfuscation is always a poor replacement for security. If objects should not be accessed you have to prevent that, not try to hide them.

Comment: Use something besides a 'pid=' to select a given product. Make a UUID or something hard to guess.

Comment: @quidage i have an error messahe says " data to render the product is unavailable" but that only comes up with the id is not in the database. AlSO am using x10hosting for this

Comment: If you have to go that route of Obfuscation I agree with @ethrbunny. I make my URL's for certain items 32 random chars that is stored in the db as an ID. I don't use the DB id that is incremented. This way they can not guess it. **BUT** I also have access rights on the pages too so it's even more secure.

Comment: @Pjack its not that i am trying to prevent anyoen from accessing the page. I am trying to prevent someone from typing in the pid.. for an example I have all my product in 1 database table. some item can be sent to item.php when u click on view. Some items can not be view in item.php but in product.php... so if u change the pid and type in 4 which is for product.php it will still show up in item.php/pid=4 which shouldn't have...

Comment: Then why not fix the code so if it doesn't exist, it returns an error page or an item not found? That's what should happen versus you trying to hide the URL.

Comment: @Pjack I am not trying to hidden the url... If i have a table which an id of up to 6 items and only 3 items can be shown on item.php page when u click on view. if i type in 4 in the url it will still load up that item which is what i dont want to happen.

Comment: I know the only way for me to stop this is not separate the product into different database tables instead of having all my products in one table. I was wondering if they is another way

Comment: SELECT size, price FROM product WHERE pid=:id LIMIT 1 that is the query i am using to run on the item.php page

Comment: so what happens if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Pjack you mean if the pid doesn't exist in the database?

Comment: @Pjack If u mean on the database the page still renders but only showing the header and footor contents but where the main contents goes you get an error message saying " sorry product not found

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of this:

1) do post on href click and then access pid from $_POST on server side

2) do base64 or custom encryption for pid value (can be coupled with 1))

3) handle manual pid change on the business  side
so it is not a problem for you, just let them do it if they want.

I would go for option 2)  but here an example of option 1)

```
        <html><body id="body"><script> function postData(val) {
        var frm = document.createElement("form")
        frm.action="/data.php";
        frm.method="post";

        var input=document.createElement("input")
        input.name="pid";
        input.value = val; 
        input.type = "hidden";

        frm.appendChild(input);

        var body= document.getElementById("body");
        body.appendChild(frm);
        frm.submit();
    } </script><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="postData(<?php echo $pid; ?>)">View</a></body></html>
```

this is example for option 2 using base64 encoding:

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($apages) ?>item.php?pid=<?php echo base64_encode($row['pid']); ?>">View</a>
```

and then in item.php:

```
$pid=base64_decode($_GET['pid']);
```

Comment: any idea where i might find an example for option 1

Comment: please do not refer to base64 as "encryption". It is nothing of the sort.

Comment: and where exactly i referred to base64 as "encryption" ?